# How to convert this line from C# to VB.net (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Hi I am studying some codes from the web that I need for a future project, but I am having trouble changing this code from C# to VB.net. Can someone help pleasE?

```
this.btnAdd.Click += btnAdd_Click;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding event handlers is done differently in VB.NET:

```
AddHandler btnAdd.Click, AddressOf btnAdd_Click
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler(btnAdd.Click, AddressOf btnAdd_Click)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most often, for simplier conversions like that, you can use the web based tool at 
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/
Though, it should be seen as a advise or guideline.